# Add Box Shadow around Image ignoring the Padding

Tags: html, css, image, padding

I want to add a `box-shadow` to three images aligned next to each other. They all have a `padding` of 10px. When I apply the box shadow, it goes **around** the padding. I want it to go around **the image**, ignoring the padding.

```css
.front-images {
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.front-images img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="front-images">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
</div>
```

I also tried adding a `margin` property instead of padding but it doesn't work. Is there a way to ignore the padding, adding the box shadow around the image?

Comment: may try drop-shadow filter instead

Comment: can you provide the full code @Wyrden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.front-images img {
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 50%); */
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px rgb(0 0 0 / 50%));
}
```